# How to close a named pipe (thereby enabling it for cat)?

Tags: bash, pipe

I need help closing a named pipe. I created a named fifo via `mkfifo myfifo`, then some C++ executable files wrote/read from `myfifo`, and now I wish to close it (so I can `cat` its contents to read them).

However, I read the `man mkfifo` page, and also googled around, but I cannot find any specific command to close the fifo (even after all executables are done using it).

---

The commands involved are:

```
$ mkfifo myfifo
$ ./A < myfifo | ./B > myfifo
$ # now i want to read myfifo
```

(the executables `A` and `B` interact with each other via `myfifo`)

---

These are the files

```
// B.cpp

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream file("inter.txt");
    int in = -1;
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        cin >> in;
        cout << (in + 1);
    }
    else
        cout << -1;
    file << in;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}

// A.cpp

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace std;
#define PIPE "pipe.txt"
#define MAX_BUF 150

int main()
{
    ofstream file("inter2.txt");
    cout << 1 << endl;
    file << 1;
    int in;
    cin >> in;
    cout << 2 * in;
    file << 2 * in;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, this is supposed to happen: A outputs 1. B reads 1 and outputs 2. A reads 2 and outputs 4. Then the programs end.

Comment: Stop `./A` or `./B`.

Comment: @Cyrus but how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is that once the contents of a FIFO have been consumed, they won't remain in the FIFO. Thus, it is not possible to print all the contents of a FIFO later (only those that weren't consumed would remain).

The only way to know what was being sent to the FIFO is to print the same thing to a separate file (possibly overload the stream insertion operator `<<`).